# Using PageStateMatcher in Google Chrome Extensions API to filter webpages with a specific keyword in their meta tags

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm learning how to program Google Chrome extensions. I want to use PageStateMatcher to match webpages including a specific keyword in their meta keywords tag. For example, if my keyword is "design", I want to show a page action in webpages if they have a tag like `<meta name="keywords" content="design, art, architecture, whatever">`. This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work because the css matcher only inspects tags inside the body tag, not the head tag:

```
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
      chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
        conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          css: ["meta[content*='design']"]
        })
        ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
      }]);
    });
```

I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Does anyone know how to do this with PageStateMatcher, or should I use an alternative? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The declarativeContent documentation explicitly says only visible elements are matched. You'll have to use a standard content script for this and send a message to the background script that will show the page action.